# Having trouble with sending data over a bluetooth connection

Tags: android, android-studio

So I know this type of question has been posted before, but I just can't understand them, I currently have a simple program which shows paired devices (works fine) and then when you press a button it should send data to the other device's TextView to edit it. Here is the code that I have, can anybody see what I'm doing wrong? I'm still new to Android Studio.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ConnectedThread connectedThread;

private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
private BluetoothDevice btDevice;
private BluetoothSocket btSocket;
private ParcelUuid[] uuids;

private OutputStream outStream;
private InputStream inStream;

private Button btnShowPaired;
private ListView lstPaired;
private Button btnSendData;
private TextView txtViewData;

private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

private Set<BluetoothDevice> setPaired;
private ArrayList<String> aryLstPairedName;

private final int MESSAGE_READ = 0;

private byte[] buffer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    connectedThread = new ConnectedThread();

    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    btnShowPaired = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowPaired);
    lstPaired = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstPaired);
    btnSendData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendData);
    txtViewData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewData);

    btnShowPaired.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setPaired = (Set)btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
            UpdateNameList();
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    lstPaired.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            List<BluetoothDevice> btList = new ArrayList<>(setPaired);

            btDevice = btList.get(position);

            try {
                SetupTransfer();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    });

    btnSendData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    setPaired = new HashSet<BluetoothDevice>();
}

public void UpdateNameList()
{
    aryLstPairedName =  new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, aryLstPairedName);
    lstPaired.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    for(BluetoothDevice device : setPaired)
    {
        aryLstPairedName.add(device.getName());
    }
}

public void SetupTransfer() throws IOException {
    ParcelUuid[] uuids = btDevice.getUuids();
    BluetoothSocket btSocket = btDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuids[0].getUuid());
    btSocket.connect();
    outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
    inStream = btSocket.getInputStream();

    connectedThread = new ConnectedThread();
    connectedThread.start();
}

public class ConnectedThread extends Thread
{
    public ConnectedThread()
    {

    }

    public void Read() throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        while(true)
        {
            try {
                bytes = inStream.read(buffer);

                mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Write(String s) throws IOException
    {
        outStream.write(s.getBytes());
    }
}

private final Handler mHandler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        switch (msg.what)
        {
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuffer = (byte[]) msg.obj;

                String readMessage = new String(readBuffer, 0, msg.arg1);
                txtViewData.append(readMessage);
        }
    }
};
```

}

Comment: do you get an error ? what the problem ? why post a vague question and expect anything ? `but I just can't understand them`, then read them again.

Comment: @svarog I was wondering if anybody knew what was going wrong, currently there are no errors but it doesn't do anything.

I've been reading a number of different tutorials all of which only contain parts of the code needed or don't work.